# Record not unique error in rails , while i'm using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 26.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

Started POST "/members" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-08 10:43:18 -0400
Processing by RegistrationController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"i1xfaMmmX6HttiUo5Xwbx35gOCKKyAo+DMAecqcOUT/cw14di/WTlZ1KrZsdiJuIhN7tjxfVXZDvSDOpGzmK5A==", "member"=>{"username"=>"asdf", "email"=>"ash@ash.in", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "contact"=>{"mobile"=>"5", "address"=>"lkdjsk"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "members" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2017-06-08 14:43:18.965179"], ["updated_at", "2017-06-08 14:43:18.965179"]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)



**ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: members.email: INSERT INTO "members" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)):**

app/controllers/registration_controller.rb:22:in `create'
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying create a member with email which is already existed.